# Grails domain List field not being persisted

Tags: grails

I have a domain class

```
class Something {
    String name
    String email
    List<String> friends = []
}
```

In the domain class itself I have a method for Something objects which populates the friends list. But for some reason I am not able to persist this list. and it gets made null on browsing away from the gsp relevant to the domain modifying action.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you instead need to write your domain as:

```
class Something {
    String name
    String email
    List friends
    static hasMany = [ friends: String ]
}
```

Comment: That's not [how Grails does it](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps)...  Updated my answer to include the List incase you require order

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion in addtion to using the .addTo... method works perfectly :-)

Comment: On a seperate note can I ask how I can call a method from a form tag in gsp? I don't want to call an action because it then tries to load the related gsp, which is not my intention.